# Description Resource Path Location Type The prefix "p" for attribute "p:sessionFactory-ref" associated with an element type "beans:bean" is not bound

Tags: java, xml, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am developing a web application using Spring, and I now I am implementing hibernate with this Spring and when I am creating **servlet-context.xml** file I got above error (Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type The prefix "p" for attribute "p:sessionFactory-ref" associated with an element type "beans:bean" is not bound) and I google it, but couldn't find any positive answer. Here is my servlet-context.xml file: I have put a comment in the file on error location.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

        <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing 
            infrastructure -->

        <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
        <annotation-driven />

        <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving 
            up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
        <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

        <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources 
            in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
        <beans:bean
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
            <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
            <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
        </beans:bean>

        <context:component-scan base-package="com.tela.pms" />

        <!-- <beans:bean id="patientService" class="com.tela.pms.service.impl.IndividualPatientServiceImpl"></beans:bean> -->

        <beans:bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
            <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <beans:property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test" />
            <beans:property name="username" value="root" />
            <beans:property name="password" value="root" />
        </beans:bean>

        <beans:bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
            <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></beans:property>
            <beans:property name="annotatedClasses">
                <beans:list>
                    <beans:value>com.pms.model.Employee</beans:value>
                </beans:list>
            </beans:property>
            <beans:property name="hibernateProperties">
                <beans:props>
                    <beans:prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</beans:prop>
                    <beans:prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</beans:prop>
                </beans:props>
            </beans:property>
        </beans:bean>

<!-- error is here-->
        <beans:bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager" p:sessionFactory-ref="sessionFactory">
        </beans:bean>


    </beans:beans>
```

Help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

Use this at the top of your .xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">
```

Notice the element added:

```
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
```

Comment: The p folder has been removed from the given url. Is there an alternative solution?

Comment: @PedroHoehlCarvalho The p-namespace is not defined in an XSD file and exists only in the core of Spring. The url "http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" will always return 404. The p-namespace is used as a shortcut to defining beans with lesser lines of xml.